# Como puedo poner comillas simples dentro de comillas simples en javaScript

Tags: javascript

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Este es el código que necesito pasarle a un componente X:

```
'fecha= '24/4/2017' ';
```

El problema es que las comillas simple de la fecha no me las lee normalmente si no que me compila con una numeración extraña como (&#39) o algo así.

Comment: Escapa las comillas con \

Answer (score 6):

Como te escribió @Yikarus en el comentario, tienes que escapar el carácter `'` usando `\` de la siguiente manera:

```
var mi_variable = 'Un \'texto\' cualquiera';
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando necesites poner el caracter con el que abres el string dentro, puedes simplemente escaparlo:

```
'\'ejemplo\''
```

Sin embargo, deberías conocer que hay varios 'niveles' con los que puedes abrir el string, permitiendo así usar el resto dentro.

- simple

```
'ejemplo'
```

- doble

```
"'ejemplo'"
```

- Multilinea

```
`
"'ejemplo'"
`
```

Answer (score 2):

"Escapar" es el término usado, significa que al ser caracteres especiales, debes "escaparlos" para que los tome como que son LITERALES y no lo estas usando como su funcionalidad especial, en este caso la funcionalidad de '' es encerrar un texto ,pero ya que no lo quieres para eso, sino literalmente las comillas simples ,las ESCAPAS.

```js
var a = "\'Hola\'";
console.log(a)
```

Comment: En tu código no hace falta "escaparlas" ya que las comillas simples están dentro de unas dobles, sólo hay que "escapar" cuando las comillas están metidas dentro de un literal que está metido dentro del mismo tipo de comillas:

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza comilla volteada.
sl2

```js
var variable = `jaaa'' so ptm`;
var cOutput = `Hola '${variable}'`;
console.log(cOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="menorDeEdad('24/4/2017')";

function menorDeEdad(fecha){
console.log(fecha);
}
```

algo asi?

quieres la fecha

```
var f = new Date();
fecha= f.getFullYear();
```

si no pues mandar el error que te aparece

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema creando controles dinámicos, así que reemplacé las comillas sencillas por símbolos diferentes "¨", al momento de leer el texto volverlos a reemplazar:

```
string control = "<input type='text' id='txtid' onkeypress='return myfunction(¨text¨, event.key);' onblur='myfunction(¨text¨, this)' maxlength='50' required />";

string result = control.Replace("'", "*").Replace("¨", "'").Replace('*', '"');
```

Como resultado me crea un control sin errores:

```
<input type="text" id="txtid" onkeypress="return SiteTools.restrictBolean('text', event.key);" onblur="SiteTools.restrictValor('text', this)" maxlength="50" required="">
```

El primer replace es para volver las comillas sencillas en un simbolo diferente "*", luego reemplacé el caracter "¨" por comillas sencillas y despues volví a poner las comillas dobles reemplazando los "*", para tu ejemplo sería algo así:

```
var control = "'fecha= ¨24/4/2017¨'";
var result = control .Replace("'", "*").Replace("¨", "'").Replace('*', '"');
```

al imprimir el resultado quedaría así:
    "fecha='24/4/2017'"

Espero les sirva.

Answer (score -1):

```
$out.= '<li><span><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="load(1,\''.$regla.'\')">'.$prevlabel.'</a></span></li>';
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).